# Firefox html dynamic imports just won't work. (using firefox 37.0a2 and polymer 0.5.1)

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

Well, i've tested importing by injecting **all** the imports inside the head with innerhtml;

Importing by injecting **each individual** import inside the head with innerhtml once clicked;

Using polymer.import method for an array with all imports once polymer-ready (others too) 
fires;

Using polymer.import method for an array with each import once user clicked the menu item;

Nothing worked. feels like FF only takes in account the imports made on the first time it parses the head. can anyone help me with some sort of workaround? Not to be arrogant but yes, my codes are fine. Its just scattered enough to discourage me to copy paste everything here.
anyone PLEASE?

Comment: Not to be arrogant but without code it is pretty hard to test exactly what you mean. If we had some code, we could see it for ourselves that it doesn't work and find a solution.

Comment: I though about that, but the issue is it's not vulcanized and it's somewhat scattered, i'll try and organize it. still, thanks for the comment. :)

Comment: Oh and BTW, it works flawless if the imports are hard coded from beginning. the problem is with adding them later dynamically.

Comment: confirmed it doesn't work. just sit and wait for html imports on FF or working polyfill. just updating.